# Prove Two Functions are Simultaneously Continuous

Tags: derivatives, contest-math, monotone-functions

> Let $f,g,h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $f$ is
> differentiable, $g,h$ monotone and $f'=f+g+h$.
>
> Prove that $g$ is continuous in $x_0$
> iff $h$ continuous in $x_0$.

---

**My attempt**

Suppose $g$ is continuous in $x_0$ and $h$ is discontinuous in $x_0$.

Monotone functions have lateral limits everywhere, therefore $h$ has lateral limits in $x_0$.

It follows that $f'$ is also discontinuous in $x_0$ (otherwise the sum of continuous functions is also continuous).

So far I have no idea how to get a contradiction out of here.

Comment: Maybe try triangular inequality?

Comment: @Misakov Sounds good, but I cannot see how.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $g$ is continuous in $t$ and $h$ is discontinuous in $t$. By definition of differentiability

$$\lim_{k\to 0^+} f'(t+k) = \lim_{k\to 0^-} f'(t+k)$$ So that:

$$\lim_{k\to 0^+} f(t+k)+g(t+k)+h(t+k)=\lim_{k\to 0^-} f(t+k)+g(t+k)+h(t+k)$$

However, we know:

$$\lim_{k\to 0^+} f(t+k) = \lim_{k\to 0^-} f(t+k) \\ 
 \lim_{k\to 0^+} g(t+k) = \lim_{k\to 0^-} g(t+k)$$

Which lives us with

$$\lim_{k\to 0^+} h(t+k) = \lim_{k\to 0^-} h(t+k)  $$

Which is a contraddiction

Comment: How do you know $f'$ is continuous in $t$? (Or, at least, has same lateral limits?)

Comment: By definiti in of differentiability! (Otherwise we could say that |x| is differentiable at x=0)

Comment: No, the first equality means $f'$ has same lateral limits.